# How to add multiple methods on the same object?

Tags: java, methods

I'm a beginner to Java. I am wondering if it is possible to add multiple methods on the same object without having to create a new one (in this case - String).

```
public class DeletAble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Refrain from saving this document

        String userName = "sdfsd".trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase().substring(1).toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(userName);

    }
}
```

The compiler does not give any errors, however nothing prints out. It works if I create another String for the `.tolowerCase()` method. Is there a way to use these methods like this, and if not: why?

Comment: What do you think `substring(0,1)` does and why do you think so? What does `substring(1)` do?

Comment: Takes the first letter and makes it upper case. "m" -> "M". Why dislike? :(. Substring(1) is supposed to make the rest of the letter lowercase...

Comment: @Aminorph you can use `charAt()` method to get a single character

Comment: Keep in mind that `String` is an immutable type.  The methods you are calling are not operating on a single instance.  Instead, a new object of `String` type is returned with each chained method call.

Comment: Are you asking about method chaining or are you asking about why you think nothing is being output?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java Strings are immutable. Whenever you "modify" it you actually create a new one.

```
public class DeletAble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Your code is esentally shorthand for the following code
        String userName = "sdfsd"           // Value "sdfsd"
        userName = userName.substring(0,1)  // Value "s"
        userName = userName.toUpperCase()   // Value "S"
        userName = userName.substring(1)    // Value ""
        userName = userName.toLowerCase()   // Value ""

        // Prints emmpty string ""
        System.out.println(userName);
    }
}
```

I am guessing that you want the following code

```
public class DeletAble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Your code is esentally shorthand for the following code
        String userName = "sdfsd"                                       // Value "sdfsd"
        String firstLetter = userName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();     // Value "S"
        String rest = userName.substring(1).toLowerCase();              // Value "dfsd"
        userNmame = firstLetter + rest;                                 // Value "Sdfsd

        // Prints emmpty string "Sdfsd"
        System.out.println(userName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Guess I felt like there were some sort of shortcut. Thanks for clearing it up. Cheers!

Comment: Well there's a "shortcut" as you can chain the calls, but the string is never modifier, you need to store the result (a new string) of those transformations

Answer (score 3):

```
 "sdfsd".trim().substring(0,1)
```

This part returns `"s"`.

```
.toUpperCase()
```

returns `"S"`

```
.substring(1)
```

returns `""`.  It *doesn't* go back to the original string you started with; it just takes `substring(1)` of the result you had, `"S"`, which is the empty string.  That's your problem.

If you want to do different things with different parts of the string, you're going to have to store it in a variable, do different things with different parts, and put it back together again.  You can't go "back up a level" like you're trying to do, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do exactly what you've got there, but this is the path your string:

```
"sdfsd" -> "sdfsd" -> "s" -> "S" -> "" -> ""
```

substring(1) gets the character at index 1, what you want is index 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you place 2 `int` arguments in the `substring` method, the first represents the index of the first character in the `String` that you wish to extract the `substring` from, the second is the index which you stop at and that index is not included in the `subsstring`. You wrote `.substring(0,1)` which means the first character will be index `0` of the String and the `substring` will go until (but not including) index `1` of the original String. This means that the resulting `String` will only have 1 character. After, you tried getting `.substring(1)` which would mean the character at index `1` of the `String` but because there is only 1 character there is no index `1` (only index `0`). That's why nothing was output. To get the results I'm assuming you originally wanted try making the 1st `substring` method: `.substring(0,2)`.